# How to decode / extract parameters from Google Cloud resource URI / path in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

Some Google Cloud API methods return path eg. `projects/example-project/metricDescriptors/custom.googleapis.com/stores/example-metric` as resource ID (instead of `example-metric`).

How can I *properly* extract parameters from resource URI/path? It's not a simple `propertyName/propertyValue` format and path template depends on resource type.

Of course, I can use regex to get last part of path, but I am looking for a more elegant way.

I browsed through documentation, but I didn't find any helpful information. There are methods to generate path (eg. `MetricServiceClient.projectMonitoredResourceDescriptorPath`) but not to convert path into map of parameters.